# How to create a test in Jmeter where a unique location header is returned

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

Sorry for the title being a little unclear, but I will do my best to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Send a xml request to the following URL `http://122.52.45.18:16000/foo/v1/TestData/ using POST.

This returns a HTTP/1.1 200 OK and a unique location header so something like `c4299g99-986f-53d6-c635-171b312333ef (location header is unique each time)

This is then added to the end of the request URL to retrieve the response(which is also an xml) via a GET. `http://122.52.45.18:16000/foo/v1/TestData/c4299g99-986f-53d6-c635-171b312333ef

In Jmeter, I have been trying to use the 
WebSocket request-response Sampler plugin to get it working but don't believe this is the right plugin to use.

What can I do in Jmeter to create a test for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. Add this sampler to `Thread Group`, choose it and change Method to POST (by Default it's GET) then select `Body Data` tab to paste the XML that you want to send.

After that you will be able to [extract and reuse the value from request](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/) with [Regular Expression Extractor](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/) (just choose `Field to check` - `Response Headers` on that screen) to send it to the next one.

Also you can [simply record a scenario](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/) with your browser and [JMeter proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#script-recorder).